# Jenkins Env Vars from file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I was wondering if someone did something like this:

```
environment {
    script {
        readYaml(file: 'customer_cfg.yaml').each { item ->
            item.key = item.value
        }
    }
}

or 

environment {
    readYaml(file: 'customer_cfg.yaml').each { item ->
        item.key = item.value
    }
}
```

I am trying to read a yaml file and add those `key=value` pair as global env. vars for my stages.
Of course, doesn't work.

error: "item.key is not a valid identifier and cannot be used for an environment variable."
So item.key is not taken as env. var name, I have tried also `evaluate("${item.key}")` or `"${item.key}"=item.value`.

The solution I used is by doing the above in one of the stages:

```
stage('Add Global Env Variables') {
    steps {
        script {
            config.configs.each { item ->
                env[item.key] = item.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: "doing the above in one of the stages" - so why don't you like this approach?

Comment: 1st curiosity, then I wasn't sure this is the right approach for global envs.
Not much doc. for declarative environment{} code.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, `environment` could only support `sh` such as this:

```
BRANCH_NAME = sh(
  script: 'echo "${GIT_BRANCH}" | sed "s|/|_|g"',
  returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

If you wanna read something from YAML, you should use a `stage` to approch that, just like your example.

Comment: Hi, yes I saw this example in their doc.
This approach lets you create only one :(, but thank you.